# SQL: XML nodes(): Identical queries: Different result

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, nodes

Three seemingly identical XML nodes() queries but the first one returns a different result on the first row for columns: Location1, Location2, Location3
Why is it different?
Thanks in advance.

```
declare @xml xml
set @xml =
'<root>
  <Location1 LocationID="10">
     <step1>apple</step1>
     <step2>banana</step2>
  </Location1>
  <Location2 LocationID="20">
     <step1>carrot</step1>
     <step2>donut</step2>
  </Location2>
  <Location3 LocationID="30">
     <step1>egg</step1>
     <step2>fry</step2>
  </Location3>
</root>'

declare @SQL nvarchar(max) = ''
declare @Col nvarchar(max) = ', N.value(''[COLNAME][1]'', ''varchar(100)'') as [COLNAME]' 
select @SQL = @SQL + replace(@Col, '[COLNAME]', N.value('local-name(.)', 'sysname'))
from @XML.nodes('//*') as T(N)
set @SQL = 'select '+stuff(@SQL, 1, 2, '')+' from @XML.nodes(''//*'') as T(N)' 
exec sp_executesql @SQL, N'@XML xml', @XML

declare @sql2 nvarchar(max) = ''
set @sql2 =
'select
n.value(''root[1]'',''varchar(100)'') as root,
n.value(''location1[1]'',''varchar(100)'') as location1,
n.value(''step1[1]'',''varchar(100)'') as step1,
n.value(''step2[1]'',''varchar(100)'') as step2,
n.value(''location2[1]'',''varchar(100)'') as location2,
n.value(''step1[1]'',''varchar(100)'') as step1,
n.value(''step2[1]'',''varchar(100)'') as step2,
n.value(''location3[1]'',''varchar(100)'') as location3,
n.value(''step1[1]'',''varchar(100)'') as step1,
n.value(''step2[1]'',''varchar(100)'') as step2
from @xml.nodes(''//*'') as t(n)'
exec sp_executesql @SQL2, N'@XML xml', @XML

select
n.value('root[1]','varchar(100)') as root,
n.value('location1[1]','varchar(100)') as location1,
n.value('step1[1]','varchar(100)') as step1,
n.value('step2[1]','varchar(100)') as step2,
n.value('location2[1]','varchar(100)') as location2,
n.value('step1[1]','varchar(100)') as step1,
n.value('step2[1]','varchar(100)') as step2,
n.value('location3[1]','varchar(100)') as location3,
n.value('step1[1]','varchar(100)') as step1,
n.value('step2[1]','varchar(100)') as step2
from @xml.nodes('//*') as t(n)
```

PS:  OK. It won't let me post this without writing more, so: Ultimately, I am trying to get SQL to parse an XML file into a table with the nodes, elements, and attributes as column headers with their respective values or subnodes listed below them. Something like this (I couldn't get the image to upload hopefully the formating will remain):

```
root      Location1      LocationID      Step1      Step2      Location2      Location3
Location1 LocationID     10
          Step1                          apple
          Step2                                     banana
Location2                20                                    LocationID
                                         carrot                Step1
                                                    donut      Step2
Location3                30                                                   LocationID
                                         egg                                  Step1
                                                    fry                       Step2
```

For some reason, this a tall order for SQL but I am still curious about why the difference in the above queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that xml element names are case sensitive. In the first query you have `Location1`, `Location2`, `Location3`, in the second `location1`, `location2`, `location3`

Comment: Duh. I should have noticed that. Thanks.